# Importing an image from a different folder

Tags: python, image, pygame

I have a folder called "game" and inside that I have lots of other folders, one of which is called "graphics". Inside "graphics" I have lots of images. I have a python script inside "game" and I want to import some images from "graphics"; however, it's not working. Here is my code:

```
import pygame, random, math, sys, os

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

createrscreen = "grafics/creratedbyscreen.png"
gamescreen = "grafics/dnagamescreen.png" 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480), 0, 32)
```

Comment: "its not working" - be more specific. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your example code looks like it's just defining two strings that look like they could be correct relative paths to the images you want to load, but there's no call to pygame.image.load().

You might want to take a look at the tutorial here: http://inventwithpython.com/chapter19.html

The second thing is that your code refers to a directory named 'grafics' whilst your question refers to 'graphics'. You'll need to use the right one, whichever it is.